# Simple Queue with 2 threads only processes half the items

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading

I have implemented a simple queue to store a list of filenames, and a method that Reads the queue, takes the next available filename, and moves the file from one folder to another folder.

This class is used to keep track of files in a folder.

```
internal class FileItem
{
    public string FullFileName { get; set; }
    public bool isLocked { get; set; }
}
```

This is my Simple Queue implementation

```
internal class MyQueue
{
    List<FileItem> FileList;
    
    public MyQueue(string FilePath)
    {
        FileList = new List<FileItem>();

        string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(FilePath);
        foreach (string file in files)
        {
            FileItem fileitem = new FileItem
            {
                FullFileName = file,
                isLocked = false
            };

            FileList.Add(fileitem);
        }
    }

  
    public FileItem GetNextAvailableItem()
    {
        FileItem item = FileList.Where(i => i.isLocked == false).FirstOrDefault();
        if (item != null) item.isLocked = true;
        return item;
    }

    public void RemoveProcessedItem(FileItem item)
    {
        FileList.Remove(item);
    }

}
```

When I run this from Single thread, it works fine.

But I am using two threads like this.

```
static void ProcessFilesInMultiThread()
{
   Task task1 = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => ReadFromQueueAndMoveFile("Thread 1"));
   Task task2 = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => ReadFromQueueAndMoveFile("Thread 2"));            
   Task.WaitAll(task1, task2);
}
```

This is the `ReadFromQueueAndMoveFile` method.

```
static void ReadFromQueueAndMoveFile(string ThreadName)
    {
        while (_queue.GetNextAvailableItem() != null)
        {
            //get next available item from queue.

            FileItem item = _queue.GetNextAvailableItem();

            if(item != null)
            {
                string FileName = Path.GetFileName(item.FullFileName);
                string SourceFilePath = Path.Combine(sourcePath, FileName);
                string DestinationFilePath = Path.Combine(destinationPath, FileName);

                File.Move(SourceFilePath, DestinationFilePath);
                Thread.Sleep(2000);
                Console.WriteLine("Successfully moved: " + FileName + " Via " + ThreadName);

                //remove item from queue.
                _queue.RemoveProcessedItem(item);
            }

            
        }
    }
```

The problem is when I run it from 2 threads, always only half of the files are being moved and I am not sure why. If the folder has 6 files then only 3 files are getting moved randomly.

Why this is happening?

Comment: You can't lock things like that using a non-atomic operation. One thread can read `IsLocked` as false and then get pre-empted by another thread which then also reads `IsLocked` as false. Then both threads will proceed as if they have an exclusive lock. I recommend you have a read of this excellent free book: https://www.albahari.com/threading/

Comment: .NET already has thread-safe queues that can handle *a lot* of threads. `ConcurrentQueue<t>` is the old one, available since 2010. That's a general purpose thread-safe queue, without asynchronous operations.  `Channel<T>` is a recent one that works similar to Go's channel. It's built *specifically* for pub/sub scenarios, with publisher and subscriber using different interfaces. `Channel<T>` offers acynchronous write/read operations so your code doesn't have to poll the queue or block waiting for an item

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that your main problem is here:

```
while (_queue.GetNextAvailableItem() != null)
{
    //get next available item from queue.
    FileItem item = _queue.GetNextAvailableItem();
```

You are calling the `GetNextAvailableItem` twice, and the value returned from the first call is discarded.

One way to solve this problem is this:

```
while (true)
{
    //get next available item from queue.
    FileItem item = _queue.GetNextAvailableItem();
    if (item == null) break;
```

Of course you should also ensure that the `MyQueue` class is thread-safe, as Gabriel suggests in [their answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71293559/11178549).

Answer (score 1):

To prevent the threads from influencing each other, a lock must be set. For this the `lock` statement is helpful. See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/statements/lock

For this purpose a lock object is defined:

```cs
private readonly object fileListLock = new object();
```

And then it is used in the `GetNextAvailableItem()` method:

```cs
    public FileItem GetNextAvailableItem()
    {
        lock (fileListLock)
        {
            FileItem item = FileList.Where(i => i.isLocked == false).FirstOrDefault();
            if (item != null) item.isLocked = true;
            return item;
        }
    }
```

and also in the `RemoveProcessedItem()` method:

```cs
    public void RemoveProcessedItem(FileItem item)
    {
        lock(fileListLock)
        {
            FileList.Remove(item);
        }
    }
```

Comment: The real solution is to create one of the built-in thread-safe collections

Comment: Added this but still it's processing only half the items.

Comment: This won't fix the problem yet. You will at least need a lock in `RemoveProcessedItem`. Otherwise, it might be possible that an item will be removed from the list while the where method in `GetNextAvailableItem` iterates over the list, which will lead to an exception.

Comment: @Bluemarble why are you writing your own queue? Use a `ConcurrentQueue<T>` or a `Channel<T>` instead.

Comment: @SomeBody Thanks for the hint, I guess I forgot the remove method.

Comment: Even after applying lock to both the methods, it's still processing half the files! not sure what is the problem. Trying to implement ConcurrentQueue as Kanavos suggested.

Answer (score -1):

I was able to rewrite my queue using `ConcurrentQueue<T>` This solved my issue.
code here:

```
internal class MyQueue
{
    ConcurrentQueue<FileItem> FileList = new ConcurrentQueue<FileItem>();
    
    public MyQueue(string FilePath)
    {
        string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(FilePath);
        foreach (string file in files)
        {
            FileItem fileitem = new FileItem
            {
                FullFileName = file,
                isLocked = false
            };

            FileList.Enqueue(fileitem);
        }
    }


    public FileItem GetNextAvailableItem()
    {
        //Deque and return object.
        FileItem DequeItem = new FileItem();
        bool isDequeSuccess = FileList.TryDequeue(out DequeItem);

        if (isDequeSuccess) return DequeItem;
        else return null;
    }

    public bool PeekIfAnyFilesLeftInQueue()
    {
        FileItem PeekItem = new FileItem();
        bool isFileExists = FileList.TryPeek(out PeekItem);
        return isFileExists;
    }


}
```

Also I had to change the invoking of these methods from multi threaded method.

```
    static void ReadFromQueueAndMoveFile(string ThreadName)
    {
        do
        {
            //get next available item from queue.

            FileItem item = _queue.GetNextAvailableItem();

            if (item != null)
            {
                string FileName = Path.GetFileName(item.FullFileName);                    

                string SourceFilePath = Path.Combine(sourcePath, FileName);
                string DestinationFilePath = Path.Combine(destinationPath, FileName);

                // Let's assume this is a long running process.
                File.Move(SourceFilePath, DestinationFilePath);
                Thread.Sleep(2000);
                Console.WriteLine("Successfully moved: " + FileName + " Via " + ThreadName);
            }
        }
        while (_queue.PeekIfAnyFilesLeftInQueue());
        
    }
```

Comment: Calling `PeekIfAnyFilesLeftInQueue` before `GetNextAvailableItem` is not a good pattern in a multithreaded environment. The information that you gain by the first call is instantly stale and useless, because another thread might consume the last available item in the queue before the current thread has the chance to do so. That's why the concurrent collections have different APIs than the normal (thread-unsafe) collections. In a multithreaded environment you need atomic operations, that prevent external interference between getting the information and acting on it.